# Instanciate with window object in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, window

i have a problem with instanciate a class with the window object, i have a namespace call UTIL and i have this class:

```
var UTIL = { Classes : {}};

UTIL.Classes.ObservationVal = function(state, id, type, context, performer, addresee, query) {
    this.query = query;
    SPEECH.Classes.ActionVal.call(this,state, id, type, context, performer, addresee);
}

UTIL.Classes.ObservationVal.prototype = new SPEECH.Classes.ActionVal();
UTIL.Classes.ObservationVal.prototype.constructor = SPEECH.Classes.ObservationVal;
```

after, i have this code:

```
var name = "ObservationVal";
var clStr = "UTIL.Classes." + name;
var obj = new window[clStr]();
```

and this last line shows the error: "window[clStr] is not a constructor"

I don't understand why fail the instanciate, when the class ObservationVal is defined out of namespace like this:

```
function ObservationVal(state, id, type, context, performer, addresee, query) {
//..
}
```

the instanciate with window works ok. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `foo["bar.baz"]` is not equal to `foo.bar.baz`. You probably need something like `window.UTIL.Classes[name]` here.